# How to output only text after a match with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am using sed to find a certain match in a text file and then put this value in to a variable, my problem is that I only want the text after the match, and not the entire line.

```
Ans=$(sed -n '/^'$1':/,/~/{/:/{p;n};/~/q;p}' $file.txt)
```

Text File

```
q1:answer1
~
q2:answer2
~
q3:answer3
~
```

Actual Output

```
q1:answer1
```

Expected Output

```
answer1
```

Comment: You can use `grep` ---> `grep -Po '(?<=q1:)\w*' file`.

Comment: The sed script you posted is FAR more complicated than it needs to be to produce the output you show from the input you show. Post a more representative input/output example or tell is if you really do just want the text on 1 line following some regular expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
Ans=$(grep -oP "^$1:\K.*" file)
```

or with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) if your `grep` version doesn't support `-P` switch :

```
Ans=$(var=$1 perl -lne '/^$ENV{var}:\K.*/ and print $&' file)
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity; caveat: `-P` is not available on all platforms (e.g., OSX).

Comment: @mklement0: Added perl version

Answer (score 3):

In case a `sed` solution is needed - e.g., *if answers could span multiple* lines:

```
Ans=$(sed -r -n '/^'$1':(.*)/,/^(~)$/ { s//\1/; /^~$/q; p; }' file.txt)
```

(OSX users: use `-E` instead of `-r`).

- Uses a backreference (`\1`) to replace the first matching line with its portion of interest; any other lines between the first matching one and the terminating `~` line are unaffected by the replacement (assuming they don't also start with `$1:`) and also printed.
- Replace `q` with `d` if you don't want to quit after the first matching range.

By contrast, *if the string of interest is limited to the line starting with `$1:`*, there's no need to also match the `~` line, and the command can be simplified to:

```
Ans=$(sed -r -n '/^'$1':(.*)/ { s//\1/p; q; }' file.txt)
```

- Remove `q;` if you don't want to quit after the first match.

However, the single-line case is more easily handled with a `grep` or `awk` solution - see @sputnick's and @anubhava's answers. If you wanted those to *quit after the first match* -- as in the snippets above and the code in the OP -- you'd need to add option `-m 1` to the `grep` solution and `; exit` to the `awk` solution (before the `}`).

Answer (score 2):

Better use awk for this:

```
ans=$(awk -F':' -v s='q1' '$1 == s {print $2}' file)
```